# How do i tackle a situation where in i need to use same functions in multiple places

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a order fulfillment system for mu E-commerce system. I am stuck in a situation. Every 1 hour 1 cron job runs and it assigns ware house and does other processes.So this is a class where i do 1 full process. I need to give option for user to do each of them individually also manually i.e. assign warehouse manually etc. So this warehouse functions will be used in multiple places i.e in cron class and warehouse class. So should i create these functions in 1 library like warehouse.php or else in cron class create instance of each class and call its functions? i am using Codeigniter.

Hope below code makes my self clear. So should i create a warehouse library or a controller is my question.
Main question is to use like this

```
class cron extends CI_Controller{

function index(){
$this->load->library('blacklist');
$this->load->library('warehouse');
$this->load->library('lsp');
$this->blacklist->function1();
$this->warehouse->function2();
}
}

or 

class cron extends CI_Controller{

function index(){
$blacklist = new blacklist();
$warehouse = new warehouse();
$lsp  = new lsp();
$blacklist->function1();
$warehouse->function2();

}
}
```

Comment: Your question is REALLY vague... To prevent yourself from downvotes, how about giving something which you have already done, like a piece of code? or post this in programmers.stack, incase you just need an advise?

Comment: @ KarmicDice - Please check question now.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a MY_Controller in your Core folder which extends CI_Controller - make your normal controllers extend MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller and put the functions you need to access from multiple controllers in there. I did something similar and then restricted my cron controller to cli requests only using an if(!$this->input->is_cli_request()){ exit(); } for added security.

Sample:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        protected function _order_export()
        {
             // Export routine goes here
        }
}
/* End of file MY_Controller.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Controller.php */
```

Make calls to this function using $this->_order_export(); in your other controllers.

Comment: please see my question now and give me suggestion.

Comment: He did give you a suggestion and for Codeigniter the correct one. This is the main purpose of being able to extend the core classes and libraaries.

Comment: Yeah, gotta love codeigniter for its extensibility - you could do it like in my example above or you could create a warehouse library and load it in where you needed it like in your first example, that would be the method most in keeping with codeigniters MVC format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Write a warehouse class/controller or set of functions that can adapt to multiple uses in different part of your system. You can then logically programme the class/function to work for each use.

**Very basic pseudo-code:**

```
If (CLI)
{
   // do this
} elseif (BATCH) {
   // do that
} elseif (MANUAL) {
   // do other
}
```

Helping you any further than this is impossible at this point as we're like blind men in a minefield.